# TableView CheckMark and Uncheck With Scroll Up Still Checked Cell Value In Ios Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

> TableView CheckMark Cell Value Removed After Scrolling Up It will Fix
>   TableView in You have face a problem many times to Checkmark after scroll Up then Scroll Down To show a Your Checkmark cell is will Removed Because cell is dequeueReusableCell So This Problem Fix , you Have just put Your code and Solved Your Problem.
>
> Any More Help So Send Massage.
>   Thank you So much. :)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate{

var temp = [Int]()
var numarr = [Int]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numarr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id")
    cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "id")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = String(numarr[indexPath.row])
    if temp.contains(numarr[indexPath.row] as Int)
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if temp.contains(numarr[indexPath.row] as Int)
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
        temp.remove(at: temp.index(of: numarr[indexPath.row])!)
    }
    else
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        temp.append(self.numarr[indexPath.row] as Int)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for i in 1...100
    {
        numarr.append(i)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: you need to update in your datasource that if the item is checked or not. Means each item in your dataSet (Array) must have a key-value pair or property indicating that whether the item is checked or not

Comment: more than that - you have to actually ask a question, and tell us what you have already done.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Make `temp` a `Set<IndexPath>` add add/remove the index path as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if someone were to run your code it would not show any error. But with real data it probably will. The **reason** is the **way you store your checkmarks**. You store the data of a row into the `temp` array when you should be storing the actualy `indexPath` of the array so that **only that row gets the checkmark**. In your case, if a row has `1` inside it's label and you click on it, that cell will be highlighted. Now if you start scrolling and another cell contains `1` then that row will also be highlighted.

I have modified your example for the case of a single section. If there is more than one section, you need to store the `indexPath` instead of `indexPath.row`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id")
    cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "id")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = String(numarr[indexPath.row])
    if temp.contains(indexPath.row) {
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if temp.contains(indexPath.row) {
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
        temp.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    } else {
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        temp.append(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are strongly discouraged from using a second array to keep the selected state.

This is Swift, an object oriented language. Use a custom struct for both `num` and the selected state.
In `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt` change the value of `isSelected` and reload the row.

And use always the `dequeueReusableCell` API which returns a non-optional cell.

```
struct Item {
   let num : Int
   var isSelected : Bool
}

var numarr = [Item]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numarr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)
    let item = numarr[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(item)
    cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    updateSelection(at: indexPath, value : true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    updateSelection(at: indexPath, value : false)
}

func updateSelection(at indexPath: IndexPath, value : Bool) {
    let item = numarr[indexPath.row]
    item.isSelected = value
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    (0...100).map{Item(num: $0, isSelected: false)}
}
```