# while scrolling the tableview the selection is missing in tableview

Tags: ios

i have used tableview(groped).
And for each section i need to select  one cell from each section of the tableview.

after selecting the cells then i scroll the tableview then the selected cell is missing .how to correct it...
this is my code:-

```
        let questionsModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:indexPath.section)
        print(questionsModel.buttontype)

        questionViewModel.button = questionsModel.buttontype


        cell.setOptions(Options1: questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

        print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

    if questionViewModel.button == "2"{
        self.selected = 1

        cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_uncheck.png"), for: .normal)

        cell.setOptions(Options1: questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

        questionViewModel.imagename = "2"

    }
    else if questionViewModel.button == "1"{
        cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
    }

    else if questionViewModel.button == "3"{


        self.selected = 1
        /////smileys/////////.................

        //   cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.setSmileyRating(Options:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

        questionViewModel.imagename = "3"

    }

    else if questionViewModel.button == "4"{
        self.selected = 1

        //   print(cell.floatRatingView.rating)

        //  cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .normal)
        cell.setStarRating(Options:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
        questionViewModel.imagename = "4"

    }

    else if questionViewModel.button == "5"{


        self.selected = 1

        cell.setOtherOptions(Options:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

        questionViewModel.imagename = "2"

    }


    if (cell.question.text == "rating_star") {

                 cell.RatingaddCell = {[weak self] in

            if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {

              //  print(i)

                print("the Selected button is \(cell.tagSelected ?? "")")

                print(i)

                cell.setStarRating(Options:(self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))!)
                print(cell.floatRatingView.rating)

                let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
                print(model?.values ?? "")


                print(cell.floatRatingView.rating)
                print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section:indexPath.section);
                self?.tableview.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                self?.tableView((self?.tableview)!, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
            }
                    print(cell.texttype.text ?? "")
        }


    }



    if (cell.question.text == "text") {
        print("text")

        cell.textadd = {[weak self] in

            if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {


                print("the selected text\(cell.textname ?? "")")

             print(i)

                print("the Selected button is \(cell.textname ?? "")")

                print(i)

                cell.setText(Options:(self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))!)

                let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
                print(model?.values ?? "")

                print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section:indexPath.section);
                self?.tableview.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                self?.tableView((self?.tableview)!, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
                }
            print(cell.texttype.text ?? "")
            self?.u = 1
        }


    }

    print(cell.question.text)
    if (cell.question.text == "smiley"){



        cell.SmileyPoorCell = {[weak self] in

            if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {


                print("the Selected button is \(cell.tagSelected)")

                print(i)

                cell.setDataSmileyRating(Options:(self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))!)

                let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
                print(model?.values ?? "")


                print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section:indexPath.section);
                self?.tableview.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                self?.tableView((self?.tableview)!, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
                  self?.u = 1

            }

        }

        cell.SmileyaddCell = {[weak self] in

            if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {


                print("the Selected button is \(cell.tagSelected)")

                print(i)

                cell.setDataSmileyRating(Options:(self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))!)

                let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
                  print(model?.values ?? "")

                print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section:indexPath.section);
                self?.tableview.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                self?.tableView((self?.tableview)!, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
          self?.u = 1
            }
        }



        cell.SmileyNothappyCell = {[weak self] in

            if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {


                print("the Selected button is \(cell.tagSelected)")

                print(i)
                cell.setDataSmileyRating(Options:(self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))!)

                let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
                 print(model?.values ?? "")

                print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section:indexPath.section);
                self?.tableview.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                self?.tableView((self?.tableview)!, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
                self?.u = 1

            }

        }
        cell.SmileyhappyCell = {[weak self] in

            if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {


                print("the Selected button is \(cell.tagSelected)")

                print(i)

                cell.setDataSmileyRating(Options:(self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))!)

                let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
                print(model?.values ?? "")
                print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section:indexPath.section);
                self?.tableview.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                self?.tableView((self?.tableview)!, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
                self?.u = 1
            }

        }
        cell.SmileySohappyCell = {[weak self] in

            if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {


                print("the Selected button is \(cell.tagSelected)")

                print(i)
                cell.setDataSmileyRating(Options:(self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))!)

                let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
                 print(model?.values ?? "")

                print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section:indexPath.section);
                self?.tableview.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                self?.tableView((self?.tableview)!, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

                  self?.u = 1
            }

        }
        cell.SmileySohappyCell = {[weak self] in

            if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {


                print("the Selected button is \(cell.tagSelected)")

                print(i)

                cell.setDataSmileyRating(Options:(self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))!)

                let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
               print(model?.values ?? "")
                print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section:indexPath.section);
                self?.tableview.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
                self?.tableView((self?.tableview)!, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
                self?.u = 1
            }

        }


    }


              return cell
```

How to make the selected cell stay there?

Comment: By maintaining the selected index somewhere and setting/resetting them in `cellForRowAt` delegate.

Comment: Check if these help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52102002/7734643, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906856/7734643

Comment: **Never ever** call delegate methods including `did`, `will` or `should` by yourself. Those methods are exclusively called by the framework.

Comment: @vadian how to correct the issues?

Comment: how to solve according to my code?

Comment: This because tableview is reusing the cell, for solving this create an status field in your tableview datasource array and each time you select change the status and give selection for cell according to this status