# Check box check and unchecked not persisting in my table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My task I am trying to show `tableView` with `check box` button inside the `popup` viewcontroller.

Whenever user click the `button` it is changing check and `uncheck` but I need to do when I click done `button` I have to keep user `checked` and if click `cancel` it should `uncheck`(which is user checked before click cancel). I need to understand and fix this task.

[image: Check and Uncheck popup]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
    cell.myCellLabel.text = self.animals[indexPath.row]

    if selectedRows.contains(indexPath)
    {
        cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
    }else{
        cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
    }
        cell.checkBox.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBoxSelection(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
}

// method to run when table view cell is tapped
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell else {
        return
    }

    if self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
        self.selectedRows.remove(at: self.selectedRows.index(of: indexPath)!)
        cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        self.selectedRows.append(indexPath)
        cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow //optional, to get from any UIButton for example
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! MyCustomCell
        }
    }

@IBAction func cancelPopup(_ sender: Any) {
    self.removeAnimate()
}

@IBAction func donePopUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.removeAnimate()
}
```

Comment: Cells are re-used, so you need to track the "checked state" ... when the state changes (due to user tap), have your cell tell the view controller to update that "checked" state in your data source.

Comment: the user may done many cells or one at a time ?? also does it one section ??

Comment: I clicked check box and make it checked and give done it should be always done until uncheck done. If i click check to uncheck or new check then click cancel it should validate which is added by done button. Could you please give me some sample.@Sh_Khan

Comment: can't understand your question clearly share what should be the output?

Comment: user clicking check box and make it check it wont persist until click done button. suppose if user click cancel button it should not persist also when next time popup up open it should be uncheck. @Sh_Khan

Comment: @pastelsdev check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906543/tableview-checkmark-and-uncheck-with-scroll-up-still-checked-cell-value-in-ios-s/51906856#51906856

Comment: @pastelsdev when user select particular cell then reload the cell only.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using  basic taleview cell with setting acessoryType . Putting checkbox and labels all at the left seems giving poor UX

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DefectCell", for: indexPath)

    let category = defectSet [indexPath.section]
    let item = category.items[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    let isFound = User.shared.selectedDefect.filter{ $0.id == item.id }.count > 0

    if (isFound)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return cell
}
```