# UITableView not check marking cells (outside of didSelect and didDeselect) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a `UITableView` where I allow the user to select cells and when they do I set the `cell.accessoryType` to `.checkmark`. My app is set up in a way that the user is supposed to go to the "main" ViewController, segue to the TableView, select a few cells, and then repeat this process a few times. My problem is that I don't want the tableView selections the user has already made to disappear. I have already tried `self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false` and it does not work. So I made an array, that contains all of the indexPaths for the cells the user has selected, so when the user goes to the "main" ViewController and comes back I want my app to essentially reselect those cells.

Here is my code for this process...

```
 for row in selectedRows {
   print("Reselecting: \(row)")
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: row)
   print(cell)
   cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
```

When I print the cell it shows up in the log like this `<UITableViewCell: 0x7fc2f90f3e00; frame = (0 0; 375 44); text = 'Title'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000aae260>>`. One thing I noticed is that the text on my cell when it is properly displayed is not Title like the log suggests (Although it is the default text in my storyboard), could this have something to do with my problem? Why are the cells not check marked after running this code?

Comment: Store the selection status along with the dataSource model that you are using to populate the cells.

Comment: This cannot work. You must not use `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRow`. Add a `isSelected` property to your model and maintain the state there. Please see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906543/tableview-checkmark-and-uncheck-with-scroll-up-still-checked-cell-value-in-ios-s/53408087#53408087)

Comment: @vikingosegundo This doesn't work either if some of the cells are off-screen. Basically manipulating the view directly is a bad choice.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I have already tried doing that and when I print the cell is shows up in the log as nil.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `tableView(_:cellForItemAt:)` from `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "<your reusable identifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCellSubclassIfAny
    cell.accessoryType = isIndexPathSelected(indexPath) ? .checkmark : .none
    // do whatever setup you need
    return cell
}
```

Of course you need to set the `dataSource` of your `tableView` (if not using `UITableViewController`. Usually it is set to the view controller which contains the `tableView`. You can do it in storyboard or in code.

Comment: I tried using this code and it did not seem to work. When is it supposed to be called? I put a print statement inside and never saw it in the log.

Comment: The dataSource is called whenever a cell is displayed on the screen....it is the place where you set the data to the cell