# tableview row is automatically deselected when I scroll down the tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

when i scroll down the tableview and the selected row is out of view the selected row is deselected and the app crashes if I select another cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! DataCell
       cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.red                   
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! DataCell
       cell.titleLable.textColor = UIColor.white

}
```

when a selected row highlighted in red is scrolled out of view it turns white.

Comment: Are you correctly set the textColor in `cellForRowAt` based on whether the cell is selected or not? You need to be.

Comment: Of course it is because cells are reused and you don't save which cell is currently selected. You should not manipulate a cell outside of `cellForRow`. For example add an `isSelected` property to the model. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906543/tableview-checkmark-and-uncheck-with-scroll-up-still-checked-cell-value-in-ios-s/53408087#53408087

Answer (score 0):

Its because cells are getting recycle when you scrolling your tableview.Make sure all your cells properties assign in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method . You can also print `indexpath.row` while scrolling tableview to find out what actually happening in background.